# How do I redirect string input into sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script that requires root access and so what I need to do is write something like

```
$my_psswd >> sudo some_command parameter1 parameter2
```

to automate the process. I'm not concerned if this opens up security holes. This is more or less of an example that I can think of. But the problem is that when I initiate sudo anything, it asks for user input which I'm not sure how automate or provide as a variable.

I've tried things like

```
$my_psswd >1 sudo something
echo $my_psswd | sudo something
```

but none of this is what I want. Also this has to be a bash script, I can't use a program like expect. Thanks.

Comment: You really need to shape up with redirection. The single wedge `>file` overwrites `file`, double appends; there is also the file descriptor syntax `2>` to specify standard error (fd 2) instead of the default 1. See a shell programming tutorial for the full scoop. Anyway, the facility you need here is the pipe `outputprogram | inputprogram`.

Comment: Ya, I'm new to bash scripting but I know what pipes and fd are. I was trying to write to stdin which I remember is fd=0 or something, but I'm going crazy trying to pipe in my input to my command. I could solve this with C, but unfortunately I need bash. For some reason echo $psswd | sudo -S cmd and things like that aren't working.

Comment: Which distro are you on?  They could have disabled `-S`.

Comment: I have ubuntu distro. man sudo tells me that the options still there, but I don't know.

Answer (score 6):

You need -S switch for sudo command:

`-S          The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device.  The password must be followed by a newline character`

Answer (score 6):

I recommend against doing this at all.  You will be storing your password in plain text which means other people may have access to it.  Or it will be visible in process listings, again available to other users.

There are a couple of alternatives to prevent this:

1. Run the entire script using sudo.  Do not use sudo in the script itself but run the entire things with elevated privileges.  The downside is off course that your might be executing things with elevated privileges that do not require it but with no more background that's impossible to say.
2. Better would be to configure your account to execute those specific commands through sudo without providing a password.  That way you can execute only the commands that need it with elevated prvileges without the problem of providing a password.
3. A workaround could be to run `sudo -l` before calling the script.  That way sudo will have an active session and won't prompt for a password.  This is only a workaround and would fail if one of the commands takes longer to execute than the configured grace time for sudo.  But in small scripts this might be an easy fix.

Comment: If I'm calling the script at system startup, how do I call it with sudo? I have ubuntu and so I've put my script in the init.d folder with a soft link to rc3.d. I've chown root my_Script.sh which doesn't work either. The only thing other than permissions that I'm worried about is the startup order. I don't know how to control that as well.

Comment: If you are running from `init.d` you already have root privileges and don't need `sudo` at all. If you need to be a different user you get that with plain `su`; for root, this too is passwordless.

Answer (score 3):

Try echo $PW | sudo -S cmd

It may work for you.

Comment: I tried echo $pw | sudo -S bash and unfortunately it didn't work so well for me.

Comment: Try it with a plainer PW, such as alphanumeric only, before adding special characters.

Comment: Rather than avoiding "special characters", wouldn't it make more sense to just write `echo "$pw"`, instead of `echo $pw`, so that the password is preserved as-is?

Answer (score 3):

you are not suppose to use sudo this way, use visudo to specify what commands are allowed to what users, then you don't need to worry about passwords.